# Rails to_json Why are timestamps breaking, and being set to 2000-01-01T01:31:35Z

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a json object in rails as follows:

```
@list = Array.new

  @list << {
    :created_at => item.created_at
  }
end

@list.to_json
```

Problem is this gets received by the browser like so:

```
"created_at\":\"2000-01-01T01:31:35Z\"
```

Which is clearly not right, in the DB it has:

```
2011-06-17 01:31:35.057551
```

Why is this happening? Any way to make sure this gets to the browser correctly?

Thanks

Comment: What type is your `created_at` column?

Comment: Have you double checked your db? made some tests here and nothing unusual...

Comment: Without any actual debugging going on its hard to say. What is the value when called from the rails console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some testing / debugging to see how that date is coming through.
For me, in Rails console (Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2)

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :014 > d = Date.parse("2011-06-17 01:31:35.057551")
 => Fri, 17 Jun 2011 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :015 > @list = {:created_at => d}
 => {:created_at=>Fri, 17 Jun 2011} 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :016 > @list.to_json
 => "{\"created_at\":\"2011-06-17\"}"
```

i.e. it's just fine. Can you see whether the date is really ok?

Answer (score 0):

The trouble lies with the way `to_json` escapes characters.  There is a very good post on the subject here:

[Rails to_json or as_json](http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/)

You may need to look into overriding as_json.